# SpringBoot and MongoDB how to abstract similar entities

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mongodb

My application has two database collections of rather similar structure. Sonar now has a few code duplication between my two controller handling the entities of these collections. So my goal is to have an abstract controller taking care of the DB interaction, but I currently have no clue on how I could achieve this.

Here my two entity classes and their shared interfaces (some setters omitted):

```
public interface Auditable {

    Audit getAudit();

    void setAudit(Audit audit);
}

public interface BinaryEntity extends Auditable {

    String getId();

    String getEntityId();

    void setEntityId(String id)

    int getVersion();

    void setVersion(int version);

    String getVersionDescription();

    String getFileName();

    MetaData getMetaData();

    Binary getFile();

}

@Data
@Document(collection = "files")
public class FileEntity implements BinaryEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String fileId;
    private int version;
    private String versionDescription;

    private String fileName;
    private String mimeType;
    private MetaData metaData;
    private Audit audit;

    private Binary file;

    public FileEntity(String fileName, String mimeType) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.mimeType = mimeType;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEntityId() {
        return fileId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEntityId(String id) {
        this.fileId = id;
    }
}

@Data
@Document(collection = "forms")
public class FormEntity implements BinaryEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String formId;
    private int version;
    private String versionDescription;

    private String fileName;
    private MetaData metaData;
    private PdfSettings settings;
    private Audit audit;
    private List<Mapping> mappings;

    private Binary file;
    private String password;

    public FormEntity(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEntityId() {
        return formId;
    }

    @Override
    public void setEntityId(String id) {
        this.formId = id;
    }

}
```

Now lets start with the insert. I tried the following but when I try to call it, I get a compile error, "BinaryController is not applicable for the arguments (User, MultipartFile, FileRepository)" though `FileRepository extends MongoRepository<FileEntity, String>`:

```
public ResponseEntity<Object> uploadFile(User principal, MultipartFile fileParam,
            MongoRepository<BinaryEntity, String> repository) {
        try {
            BinaryEntity binary = createFormFromMultipart(fileParam);
            binary.setAudit(Audit.buildCreated(userService.getUser(principal)));
            repository.insert(binary);
            binary.setEntityId(binary.getId());
            binary.setVersion(1);
            repository.save(binary);
            return ResponseUtils.sendResponseObjectAsJson(binary, HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error(COULD_NOT_UPLOAD + ": ", e);
            return ResponseUtils.sendResponseObjectAsJson(COULD_NOT_UPLOAD_MESSAGE, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
    }
```

Is this even somehow possible and if yes, how could I achieve this?

EDIT:
As I still didn't get any answers or even a comment, I was playing around a bit and managed a partial abstraction. All the `repository` methods are still in the inheriting controllers and wrapped in an abstract method:

```
abstract BinaryEntity createFormFromMultipart(MultipartFile fileParam) throws IOException;

abstract BinaryEntity insert(BinaryEntity entity);

abstract BinaryEntity save(BinaryEntity entity);

abstract Optional<? extends BinaryEntity> findById(String dbId);

abstract Optional<? extends BinaryEntity> findLatestVersion(String entityId);

abstract Optional<? extends BinaryEntity> findByVersion(String entityId, int version);
```

But still, there must be a way that I could provide a generic `MongoRepository` to my abstract controller.